# Parser for simple esoteric language in Rust

Tags: rust, compiler

I am writing a compiler for esoteric language as one of my first Rust projects. I am using rust-pest to generate a parser. Since I'm new in Rust, code review would be great.

Full source code can be found [here](https://github.com/fexolm/jfec).

Here are some code snippets.

Thanks in advance.

ast.rs

```rust
use std::rc::Rc as Rc;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Module {
    pub functions: Vec<FnDecl>
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct FnDecl {
    pub name: String,
    pub inputs: Vec<Arg>,
    pub output: String,
    pub body: Rc<Stmt>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Arg {
    pub typ: String,
    pub name: String,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Stmt {
    Invalid,
    Assign(AssignStmt),
    Block(BlockStmt),
    Expr(Rc<Expr>),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct AssignStmt {
    pub name: String,
    pub typ: String,
    pub value: Rc<Expr>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct BlockStmt {
    pub list: Vec<Rc<Stmt>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Expr {
    Id(IdExpr),
    Call(CallExpr),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct IdExpr {
    pub name: String
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct CallExpr {
    pub name: String,
    pub params: Vec<Rc<Expr>>,
}
```

parser.rs

```rust
use pest::iterators::Pair;
use pest::Parser;

use std::io;
use crate::ast;

use super::utils;

#[derive(Parser)]
#[grammar = "parser/grammar.pest"]
struct JFECParser;

fn parse_arg(arg_p: Pair<Rule>) -> Result<ast::Arg, io::Error> {
    let mut iter = arg_p.into_inner();
    let name = utils::next_string(&mut iter)?;
    let typ = utils::next_string(&mut iter)?;
    return Ok(ast::Arg { name, typ });
}

fn parse_args(args_p: Pair<Rule>) -> Result<Vec<ast::Arg>, io::Error> {
    let mut res = vec!();
    for p in args_p.into_inner() {
        match p.as_rule() {
            Rule::param => {
                let arg = parse_arg(p)?;
                res.push(arg);
            }
            _ => unreachable!(),
        }
    }
    return Ok(res);
}

fn parse_call_params(call_params_p: Pair<Rule>) -> Result<Vec<Box<ast::Expr>>, io::Error> {
    let mut res = vec!();
    for p in call_params_p.into_inner() {
        match p.as_rule() {
            Rule::expr => {
                let expr = parse_expr(p)?;
                res.push(expr);
            }
            _ => unreachable!(),
        }
    }
    Ok(res)
}

fn parse_call_expr(call_expr_p: Pair<Rule>) -> Result<Box<ast::Expr>, io::Error> {
    let mut name = String::default();
    let mut params = vec!();
    for expr_p in call_expr_p.into_inner() {
        match expr_p.as_rule() {
            Rule::id => {
                name = utils::to_string(expr_p);
            }
            Rule::call_params => {
                params = parse_call_params(expr_p)?;
            }
            _ => unreachable!()
        }
    }
    Ok(Box::new(ast::Expr::Call(ast::CallExpr { name, params })))
}

fn parse_expr(expr_p: Pair<Rule>) -> Result<Box<ast::Expr>, io::Error> {
    let expr = utils::inner_next(expr_p)?;
    match expr.as_rule() {
        Rule::id => {
            return Ok(Box::new(
                ast::Expr::Id(ast::IdExpr { name: utils::to_string(expr) })));
        }
        Rule::call_expr => {
            return parse_call_expr(expr);
        }
        _ => unreachable!(),
    }
}

fn parse_stmt(stmt_p: Pair<Rule>) -> Result<Box<ast::Stmt>, io::Error> {
    let stmt = utils::inner_next(stmt_p)?;
    match stmt.as_rule() {
        Rule::assign_stmt => {
            let mut iter = stmt.into_inner();
            let name = utils::next_string(&mut iter)?;
            let typ = utils::next_string(&mut iter)?;
            let val = utils::get_next(&mut iter)?;
            let value = parse_expr(val)?;
            return Ok(Box::new(ast::Stmt::Assign(
                ast::AssignStmt { name, typ, value }
            )));
        }
        Rule::expr_stmt => {
            let next = utils::inner_next(stmt)?;
            let expr = parse_expr(next)?;
            return Ok(Box::new(ast::Stmt::Expr(expr)));
        }
        Rule::block_stmt => {
            let block = parse_block(stmt)?;
            return Ok(block);
        }
        _ => unreachable!(),
    }
}

fn parse_block(block_p: Pair<Rule>) -> Result<Box<ast::Stmt>, io::Error> {
    let mut list = vec!();
    let next = utils::inner_next(block_p)?;
    for p in next.into_inner() {
        match p.as_rule() {
            Rule::stmt => {
                let stmt = parse_stmt(p)?;
                list.push(stmt);
            }
            _ => unreachable!(),
        }
    }
    Ok(Box::new(ast::Stmt::Block(ast::BlockStmt { list })))
}

fn parse_fn_decl(fndecl_p: Pair<Rule>) -> Result<ast::FnDecl, io::Error> {
    let mut name = String::default();
    let mut inputs = vec!();
    let mut output = String::default();
    let mut body = Box::new(ast::Stmt::Invalid);

    for p in fndecl_p.into_inner() {
        match p.as_rule() {
            Rule::id => {
                name = p.as_str().to_string();
            }
            Rule::param_list => {
                inputs = parse_args(p)?;
            }
            Rule::ret_typ => {
                output = utils::to_string(p);
            }
            Rule::block_stmt => {
                body = parse_block(p)?;
            }
            _ => unreachable!(),
        }
    }
    Ok(ast::FnDecl { name, inputs, output, body })
}


pub fn create_ast(text: &String) -> Result<ast::Module, io::Error> {
    let mut parsed = JFECParser::parse(Rule::program, &text).expect("parse error");
    let module = utils::get_next(&mut parsed)?;

    let mut fn_decls = vec!();
    for decl in module.into_inner() {
        match decl.as_rule() {
            Rule::decl => {
                let next = utils::inner_next(decl)?;
                let decl = parse_fn_decl(next)?;
                fn_decls.push(decl);
            }
            Rule::EOI => (),
            _ => unreachable!(),
        }
    }
    Ok(ast::Module { functions: fn_decls })
}
```

utils.rs

```rust
use pest::iterators::{Pair, Pairs};
use pest::RuleType;
use std::io;
pub fn to_string<R: RuleType>(p: Pair<R>) -> String {
    p.as_str().to_string()
}

pub fn next_string<R: RuleType>(p: &mut Pairs<R>) -> Result<String, io::Error> {
    let next = get_next(p)?;
    Ok(to_string(next))
}

pub fn get_next<'s, 't, R: RuleType>(p: &'s mut Pairs<'t, R>) -> Result<Pair<'t, R>, io::Error> {
    if let Some(val) = p.next() {
        Ok(val)
    } else {
        Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::InvalidInput, "Fail to get next element"))
    }
}

pub fn inner_next<R: RuleType>(p: Pair<R>) -> Result<Pair<R>, io::Error> {
    get_next(&mut p.into_inner())
}
```

grammar.pest

```
WHITESPACE = _{ " " | "\t" | "\r" | "\n" }

program = { SOI ~ decl* ~ EOI }

decl = { fn_decl }

fn_decl = { "fn" ~ id ~ "(" ~ param_list? ~ ")" ~ ret_typ ~ block_stmt }

ret_typ = { ("->" ~ id)? }

block_stmt = { "{" ~ stmt_list ~ "}" }

param  = { id ~ ":" ~ id }

param_list = { param ~ ("," ~ param)* }

stmt_list = { stmt* }

stmt = { assign_stmt | expr_stmt | block_stmt }

assign_stmt = { "let" ~ id ~ ":" ~ id ~ "=" ~ expr ~ ";"}

expr_stmt = { expr ~ ";" }

expr = { call_expr | id }

call_params = { expr ~ ("," ~ expr)* }

call_expr = { id ~ "(" ~ call_params? ~")" }

id = @{ ASCII_ALPHA+ }
```

The language looks like rust. Currently only function decls and assign statements are supported. See the code snippet below.

```rust
fn foo( a: int, b: int, c: int ) -> int { 
    let a: int = bar(baz(x, y), z); 
}
```

Comment: Please tell us a bit about the language.

Comment: @200_success, language looks like rust, right now it supports function decls, assign statements and function call exprs.  
This looks like
```rust
fn foo( a: int, b: int, c: int ) -> int {
    let a: int = bar(baz(x, y), z);
}
```
I have added grammar.pest to make it more clear.

Comment: No worries - welcome to Code Review!  I hope you get some good answers (I don't know Rust myself, so not willing to stick my neck out here!)